# how to implement pineed column in mui data grid rtl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way to implement scrolling of headers column when there are pinned columns through css or apiRef?

I succeded to do with css only on the header columns, or with pinned columns with the apiRef but in this case the problem is that the size of the grid changed through diffrenet screens and it take some time till the size is set but the calcultion if needed a scroller is happen before.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.